# How to implement parallel prefix sum algo in c?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

Here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i,s=0,j,c=8;
    int a[]={3,1,0,4,2,1,2,3};
    int l=ceil(log10(c)/log10(2));
    #pragma omp parallel for
     for (i = 1; i < c-1; ++i)
    {   
        for (j = 0; j <l ; j++)
        {
            if(i-pow(2,j)>=0){
            a[i]+=a[(i-(int)pow(2,j))];//printf("%i %i %i %i\n", i,j,a[i],a[(i-(int)pow(2,j))]);
        }
        }   
    }
   for (i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        printf("%i\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but i am getting wrong answer,what i found is that i am getting wrong answer because the pragma loop is working sequentially, the array a is getting updated before all iteration gets completed.
i used this algo

```
for all Pi where 1<=i<=n-1
    for j = 1 to ceil(log n) -1 
        if(i- pow(2,j)>=0)
            a[i ] = a[i] + a[i - 2j]
```

Comment: i added the algo above as in my book

Comment: can u please post a working program

Comment: First off both `i` and `j` need to be made private. Second off, you have an interdependence among your loops. `a[i-(int)pow(2,j)]` can be edited by a thread working on a different iteration of `i` than the current thread, causing a race condition. You have to change your algorithm fundamentally; as-is this is not a parallel algorithm.